# Amazon Aurora memory overflow

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-aurora

I created an Amazon Aurora instance few weeks ago , it was doing great at the beginning and memory current value was 13,000 MB , Everyday current value of memory is reduced by a certain amount and now it is only 781 MB.
I don't know if it is a cache problem or I have something wrong with my configuration any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: What does the `current value` represent?  Allocated memory or available memory?  I'm assuming by your wording that it's available memory and that it is consuming more as time goes on, but it's a bit ambiguous in the chart...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that MySQL tries to cache data and use memory as long as it has free space , so If you want to change this, you could use different configuration other than Amazon RDS configuration.

By default : `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is `{DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4}`

I changed it to `innodb_buffer_pool_size` = `{DBInstanceClassMemory*1/2}`

and that solved my problem.

Comment: I'm also using an Aurora instance.  It's not performing well.  When I look at the variables (SHOW VARIABLES;), I don't even see INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE.  Any idea why this might be?

Comment: On my Aurora MySQL 5.7 instance, I can see it: `select @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;`